# Implementing BlueCove in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluecove

Has anyone successfully worked with BlueCove in Android?
I've tried to add bluecove.jar in my project but i get the message: The library 'bluecove-2.1.0.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.

Has anyone had and solved this issue?

Comment: The error means what it says. Android devices are ARM. That was compiled for an x86 processor, probably. (See, native). Having worked with Android's bluetooth stack, I don't see why you need an external library.

Comment: Ok thanks. I need to use OBEX and i really don't know how to do

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link:

http://groups.google.com/group/bluecove-developers/msg/847f714034b34126

and in [ Window -> Preference -> Android -> Build ] unckeck first two voices:

1) Automatically refresch resource....

2) Force error.....

I solved in this way